# TypeScript: Lambdas and using 'this'

Tags: lambda, typescript, this

JavaScript frameworks often call callbacks using apply().

TypeScript's arrow notation, however, doesn't seem to allow me to access the 'this' pointer.

How's it done?

If it isn't, is there a place to down-vote the current 'this' handling on Lambdas?

Comment: Tip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeScript's handling of `this` in arrow functions is in line with ES6 (Read: [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)). Due to that specification, it would be inconsistent for it to act any other way.

If you want to access `this` of the current function, then you can use a regular function.

For example, change:

```
function myScope() {
    var f = () => console.log(this); // |this| is the instance of myScope
    f.call({});
}

new myScope();
```

To:

```
function myScope() {
    var f = function() { console.log(this); } // |this| is {}
    f.call({});
}

new myScope();
```

Comment: I see. But changing the meaning of the `this` pointer for Lambda expressions and thereby introducing diverging behaviour depending on how a function is declared doesn't introduce clarity, as I believe. Instead it adds ambiguity and trouble. Is there a link to discuss this for ECMA 262 - 6?

Comment: @AxD It's definitely too late. ES6 is scheduled for publication this month ([June 2015](https://twitter.com/awbjs/status/474662357516689410)).

Answer (score 4):

One way to have the Lambda function working with the keyword **this**, is to have it inside a class.

In the following example, the function employee2 will not compile:

```
// Using a method defined as a lambda function
class Company{
    private id : number
    private name : string;

    public employee = (id : number, name : string) => {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

// Using a function declaration
function employee1(id : number, name : string){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

// Using a lambda function
const employee2 = (id : number, name : string) => {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

// Using a function expression
const employee3 = function(id : number, name : string){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
```